# How to store day wise timetable in database?

Tags: database, laravel

I am working on a school management system
I want to store time table based on day, class, section, subjects, teacher and time.
I am confused about how to design table and how to store data.
[time table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04N0K.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are new in this community. Your question does not provide proper information. Guessing you are trying to create a table named 'time' with attributes day, class, section, subjects, teacher and time.

In phpmyadmin you can do this easily by create table option. In case of laravel you need to create migrations and use **'php artisan migrate'** command. you can follow below link for further clarification- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations